# Incorrect results drawing horizontal and vertical lines to the LFB returned by VBE

Tags: assembly, plot, x86, kernel, vesa

I finally managed to draw a cyan pixel on the screen using the VESA BIOS Extensions (1920px * 1080px, 24bpp).

```
;esi = bytes per scan line
;edx = physical address of linear framebuffer memory.
;ebx = x coord * 3
;ecx = y coord

DrawPixel:
    push edx
    mov edx, 0
    mov eax, 0
    lea eax, [esi]
    ;mov ecx, 0
    mul ecx
    add eax, ebx
    jmp draw

draw:
    pop edx
    add edx, eax
    mov ebx, 0x3296fa

    mov [edx], ebx
    ret
```

I tried to draw a cyan horizontal line on the screen using a "for loop" this way:

```
mov edi, 1920
call drawLoop
jmp $

drawLoop:
    dec edi                                       ;decrease edi
    cmp edi, 0                                    ;is edi equal to zero?
    jl doneLoop                                   ;then return
    imul ebx, edi, 3                              ;multiply edi by three and save the result in ebx
    mov ecx, 0                                    ;y = 0
    mov esi, ModeInfoBlock + 10h
    mov edx, dword[ModeInfoBlock + 28h]
    call DrawPixel                                ;Draw it!
    jmp drawLoop                                  ;run this again

doneLoop:
    ret
```

However, this doesn't work: it draws a green line instead.

---

When I try to draw a vertical line again with the draw/draw pixel code, it doesn't work either. It plots pixels with random colors everywhere. Here's how I use the `DrawPixel` function to draw a vertical line:

```
%include "../kernel/Services/Display/display.asm"

kernel:
    mov edi, 1080
    call drawLoop
    jmp $

drawLoop:
    dec edi
    cmp edi, 0
    jl doneLoop
    mov ecx, edi
    mov ebx, 0
    mov esi, ModeInfoBlock + 10h
    mov edx, dword[ModeInfoBlock + 28h]
    call DrawPixel
    jmp drawLoop

doneLoop:
    ret
```

Any way to solve these problems?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214966/discussion-on-question-by-marshmallow-vbe-outputs-green-line-instead-of-cyan).

Comment: I've added to my answer new routines to draw horizontal and vertical lines. Hope you like them...

Comment: @SepRoland Of course I do!

Comment: @SepRoland I'm thinking about writing my kernel in C instead.

Comment: No matter the language you choose, most of the suggestions that make for good assembly code will also be useful in the other language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by re-writing the *DrawPixel* routine. Currently it's a bit of a mess!

There's no point in using the `mul` instruction that will clobber the `EDX` register needlessly. Better use a variant of `imul`.

And instead of using `mov eax, 0` `lea eax, [si]` to load the `EAX` register, why don't you simply write `mov eax, esi`?

There's also an error to consider. Because you're working on a 24-bit true color screen, writing a whole dword (32 bits) will change part of an adjacent pixel.

```
;esi = bytes per scan line
;edx = physical address of linear framebuffer memory.
;ebx = x coord * 3
;ecx = y coord

; IN (ebx,ecx,edx,esi) OUT () MOD (eax)
DrawPixel:
    mov     eax, esi                ; BytesPerScanLine
    imul    eax, ecx                ; BytesPerScanLine * Y
    add     eax, ebx                ; BytesPerScanLine * Y + X * 3
    mov     word [edx+eax], 0x96FA  ; Low word of RGB triplet
    mov     byte [edx+eax+2], 0x32  ; High byte of RGB triplet
    ret
```

This new routine now only modifies the `EAX` register

---

The *main* part has problems of its own:

The `mov esi, ModeInfoBlock + 10h` will not retrieve the *BytesPerScanLine* info. For that to happen you would need `movzx esi, word [ModeInfoBlock + 10h]`

The loop uses 2 branches on every iteration. It's perfectly possible to write the loop with a single branch.

Next is my version of it. Because the new *DrawPixel* routine preserves all the registers (except `EAX`) great simplifications are possible:

```
    xor     ebx, ebx                         ; X = 0  -> EBX = X * 3
    xor     ecx, ecx                         ; Y = 0
    movzx   esi, word [ModeInfoBlock + 10h]  ; BytesPerScanLine
    mov     edx, [ModeInfoBlock + 28h]       ; PhysBasePtr
    call    drawLoop
    jmp     $

drawLoop:
    call    DrawPixel                        ; Modifies EAX
    add     ebx, 3                           ; Like X = X + 1
    cmp     ebx, 1920*3                      ; Length of the line is 1920 pixels
    jb      drawLoop
    ret
```

My version draws this horizontal line from left to right. I believe it could be a tiny bit faster than drawing from the right to the left.

Instead of using a separate loop counter (`EDI`), I control the loop via the tripled-X coordinate. Amongst other benefits (like speed because `cmp`and `jb` pair up nicely) this relieves the pressure on register use.

### Better horizontal and vertical line drawing routines

Especially for drawing horizontal and vertical lines, it is not a good idea to repeatedly call a *DrawPixel* routine. It's a waste of time to calculate the pixel's address over and over again. Below I show a couple routines specifically for these tasks.

I've added some extra changes:

- You should not burden the main program with the technical details of addressing the video memory. Have the graphics routines retrieve the *BytesPerScanLine* and *PhysBasePtr* values.
- The main program should deal with pixels at the (X,Y) level. That "*times 3*" stuff again is a technical detail that belongs to the graphics routines.
- Hard coding the color in the drawing routines is very much not flexible.

```
; IN (eax,ebx,ecx,edx) OUT () MOD (eax)
; EAX = X
; EBX = Y
; ECX = Color
; EDX = Line length
HLine:
    push    edx
    push    edi
    movzx   edi, word [ModeInfoBlock + 10h]  ; BytesPerScanLine
    imul    edi, ebx                         ; BytesPerScanLine * Y
    imul    eax, 3                           ; X * 3
    add     edi, eax                         ; BytesPerScanLine * Y + X * 3
    add     edi, [ModeInfoBlock + 28h]       ; ... + PhysBasePtr
    mov     eax, ecx                         ; Color 24 bits
    shr     eax, 8
    imul    edx, 3                           ; Line length * 3
    add     edx, edi                         ; Address of the end of line
.a: mov     [edi], cx                        ; Low word of RGB triplet
    mov     [edi+2], ah                      ; High byte of RGB triplet
    add     edi, 3                           ; Like (X + 1)
    cmp     edi, edx
    jb      .a
    pop     edi
    pop     edx
    ret
```

The above *HLine* routine draws a horizontal line from left to right.

```
; IN (eax,ebx,ecx,edx) OUT () MOD (eax)
; EAX = X
; EBX = Y
; ECX = Color
; EDX = Line length
VLine:
    push    edx
    push    esi
    push    edi
    movzx   esi, word [ModeInfoBlock + 10h]  ; BytesPerScanLine
    mov     edi, esi
    imul    edi, ebx                         ; BytesPerScanLine * Y
    imul    eax, 3                           ; X * 3
    add     edi, eax                         ; BytesPerScanLine * Y + X * 3
    add     edi, [ModeInfoBlock + 28h]       ; ... + PhysBasePtr
    mov     eax, ecx                         ; Color 24 bits
    shr     eax, 8
    imul    edx, esi                         ; Line length * BytesPerScanLine
    add     edx, edi                         ; Address of the end of line
.a: mov     [edi], cx                        ; Low word of RGB triplet
    mov     [edi+2], ah                      ; High byte of RGB triplet
    add     edi, esi                         ; Like (Y + 1)
    cmp     edi, edx
    jb      .a
    pop     edi
    pop     esi
    pop     edx
    ret
```

The above *VLine* routine draws a vertical line from top to bottom.

This is how you could use these:

```
Main:
    xor     eax, eax                         ; X = 0
    xor     ebx, ebx                         ; Y = 0
    mov     ecx, 0x003296FA                  ; Color cyan
    mov     edx, 1920                        ; Line length
    call    HLine                            ; -> (EAX)
    mov     edx, 1080
    call    VLine                            ; -> (EAX)
    jmp     $
```

Comment: `lea eax, [si]` is equivalent to `movzx eax, si`, not `mov eax, esi`, in case the caller doesn't zero-extend the register arg.  (I guess the caller does do that in this case, though.)

Comment: There are two versions of the code. Drawing a horizontal line of 1920 pixels and the second is draw a vertical line of 1080 pixels. Just so happens they only provided an answer for their original question about the horizontal line and not the vertical one. The history of this question was originally just a horizontal question. When the comments solved that problem they added the edit with the vertical version that didn't work. If they edited their answer to add the solution for vertical drawing then it would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

### Drawing Horizontal Line

Based on comments I solved my problem with drawing the horizontal line by only writing 3 bytes to the video display instead of 4 bytes for each pixel. The extra byte was altering the color of the next pixel on the screen. My revised code looks like:

```
DrawPixel:
    push edx
    mov edx, 0
    mov eax, 0
    mov eax, esi
    mul ecx
    add eax, ebx
    jmp draw

draw:
    pop edx
    add edx, eax
    mov word[edx], 0x96fa
    mov byte[edx + 2], 0x32
    ret
```

---

### Drawing Vertical Line

In the code that generates a vertical line I managed to fix the issue by replacing `mov esi, ModeInfoBlock + 10h` with `movzx esi, word[ModeInfoBlock + 10h]`.

Because the `movzx` instruction moves the 16bit `bytesPerScanLine` value into the 32bit `esi` register and fills the rest with zeros. It stands for "**mov**e **z**ero e**x**tend".

My revised vertical drawing code:

```
%include "../kernel/Services/Display/display.asm"
kernel:
    mov edi, 1920
    call drawLoop
    jmp $

drawLoop:
    dec edi
    cmp edi, 0
    jl doneLoop
    imul ebx, edi, 3
    mov ecx, edi
    movzx esi, word[ModeInfoBlock + 10h]
    mov edx, dword[ModeInfoBlock + 28h]
    call DrawPixel
    jmp drawLoop

doneLoop:
    ret
```

These are my final drawing functions:

```
;esi = bytes per scan line
;edx = physical address of linear framebuffer memory.
;ebx = x coord * 3
;ecx = y coord

DrawPixel:
    push edx
    mov edx, 0
    mov eax, 0
    mov eax, esi
    mul ecx
    add eax, ebx
    jmp draw

draw:
    pop edx
    add edx, eax
    mov word[edx], 0x96fa
    mov byte[edx + 2], 0x32
    ret
```

Comment: `mov esi, word[ModeInfoBlock + 10h]` wouldn't assemble (dword destination, word source, and the mnemonic isn't movsx or movzx); your original code was moving the address into `esi`, not a value from memory.  Your answer also doesn't mention the other necessary change: only storing 3 bytes, not 4, to avoid stepping on neighbouring pixels.

Comment: The *revised vertical drawing code* has problems! Because of `EDI=1920` (should be 1080), the line starts **off screen** (could page fault). Also it is not a vertical line because the X-coordinate in **`EBX` is not kept constant**.